# Trying to save image with high resolution(200 ppi)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimage

In ios, by default while saving the image. It will renders 72 ppi image. But i want 200 or more dpi image.Resolution should not be change.
For example if i have 1200x1200 dimension image, while saving image it is 72 ppi but i wanted it as 200 or more ppi with same 1200x1200 dimensions

**Code:**

```
CGSize finalCanvasSize = CGSizeMake(1200*1200);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalCanvasSize, NO, 0.0);

[canvasImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,finalCanvasSize.width,finalCanvasSize.height)];

resizedCanvasImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: can you show the code of HOW you are saving the image?

Comment: I do not have much knowledge on it. But I think this command can help you CGContextSetInterpolationQuality.